# Obtener promedio por minuto con Python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Estoy realizando calculo matemático sobre la obtención de datos por segundo, tengo entendido que Python con Panda, es posible agrupar sobre un conjunto de datos o segmento:

Para que tengan una idea de mi registro de datos almacenados en db

```html
time A
1552403400 12
1552403401 23
1552403402 1
1552403403 2
.. ..
1552403457 1
1552403458 20
1552403459 21
1552403460 21
1552403461 34
1552403462 1
1552403463 2
1552403464 1
.. ..
1552403516 12
1552403517 4
1552403518 17
1552403519 17
1552403520 18
```

Lo que estoy intentando hacer, es agrupar los segundos "time" y obtener un promedio de la columna "A", como información final:

```html
time A
1552403400 Valor Promedio
1552403460 Valor Promedio
```

Hasta hora tengo algo como lo siguiente:

```html
query = "SELECT * FROM datos WHERE id = '%s' AND time BETWEEN %s AND %s" % (id,str(inicio),str(fin))
  print query
  data = pd.read_sql_query(query, con)
  last_time = chunk_time

  data['per_minuto'] = (data['time'].apply(int)).apply(int)
  #print data['per_minuto']
  grouped_per_time = data.groupby('per_minuto')
```

Pero lo anterior me sigue devolviendo por segundo.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo con la información que suministras, intenté recrear la información que tienes. Usando la librería `pandas` cree un `dataframe` de nombre `df`con la siguiente estructura:

```
   time        A
0  1552403428  16
1  1552403434  33
2  1552403403  24
3  1552403433  28
4  1552403407  20
Dimensiones: (100, 2)
```

Contiene en total 100 registros generados aleatoriamente. Para agrupar por la columna `time` debes tener valores repetidos, de lo contrario, el resultado será el mismo `dataframe`. Para comprobar esto puedes ejecutar:

```
print(f'Número de registros: {len(df)}')
print(f'Número de resgistros únicos {len(pd.unique(df.time))}')

# Número de registros: 100
# Número de resgistros únicos 50
```

Como ves, de los 100 registros 50 son únicos, lo que quiere decir que el dataframe resultante después de realizar el agrupado tendrá 52 registros. Con el siguiente código puedes agrupas por la columna `time` y obtener el promedio de la columna `A`, tal y como mencionas arriba.

```
groupby_seconds = df.groupby(['time']).agg({'A': 'mean'})
print(groupby_seconds.head())

#          time          A
# 0  1552403400  12.000000
# 1  1552403401  15.666667
# 2  1552403403  17.000000
# 3  1552403406  33.333333
# 4  1552403407  20.000000
# Dimensiones: (50, 2)
```

Puedes comprobar el resultado de cualquiera de los registros, en este caso, comprobaré el promedio del registro `1552403401` de la siguiente forma:

```
print(df[df.time == 1552403401])

#   time         A
#21  1552403401  10
#32  1552403401  21
#97  1552403401  16
```

Puedes comprobar que efectivamente el promedio de la columna A es: `15.666667`

Espero te sirva.